# How to use tab to generate a list of possible entries in my folder?

Tags: bash, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I am using iTerm on my mac and ZSH and oh my zsh with the theme `dstufft`

I wrote this in my `.bash_rc`

```
 function goToPythonApp {
        # no params given
        if [ -z "$1" ]; then
            cd ~/Documents/Apps/PythonApps
        else
            cd ~/Documents/Apps/PythonApps/$1
        fi
   }
```

so I can type `goToPythonApp abc`

Then I will switch to `~/Documents/Apps/PythonApps/abc`

But sometimes, I forget the name of the folder in `~/Documents/Apps/PythonApps/`

Is there a way to type `goToPythonApp` and then press `<space>` then press `<tab>` to generate a list of entries in `~/Documents/Apps/PythonApps/`?

Similar to how ZSH (or oh-my-zsh) can do autocomplete for half typed commands?

Either that or I can type `goToPythonApp ab` then press `<tab>` and the auto complete suggests `abc` which is a valid entry in the folder `~/Documents/Apps/PythonApps/`?

**UPDATE**

Used the technique suggested in the answer below then I got a `command not found for complete`.

Then I added `autoload bashcompinit && bashcompinit` before I source the `.bash_rc file`

The `command not found for complete` was gone but the tab still doesn't work

Comment: you have to do programmable completion for something like this

Comment: Why/how are you using a file named `.bash_rc` with Z shell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Zsh, you don't need your function. Add the following to your `.zshrc` file:

```
setopt autocd
pyapps=~/Documents/Apps/PythonApps
```

`autocd` lets you change to a directory just by typing the name of the directory, rather than using the `cd` command explicitly.

Static named directories (described in `man zshexpn` under FILENAME GENERATION) lets you define ~-prefixed aliases for directories. As long as `pyapps` isn't the name of a user on your system, the contents of the variable replace `~pyapps` anywhere you use it.

Combining the two features,

- `~pyapps` is equivalent to `cd "$pyapps"`
- `~pyapps/Project1` is equivalent to `cd "$pyapps/Project1"`
- `~pyapps/<TAB>` will let you use tab completion on the contents of `$pyapps`.

Comment: This works well except that it's setopt and not setoption. Everything works as you mentioned. Thank you~!!

Comment: Thanks to tab completion, I didn't really pay attention to what `seto` expanded to :)

Answer (score 2):

you can you use bash completion features to handle this

add this script to your rc file or your bash_profile file, then reopen your terminal

```
function goToPythonApp {
        # no params given
        if [ -z "$1" ]; then
            cd ~/Documents/Apps/PythonApps/
        else
            cd ~/Documents/Apps/PythonApps/$1
        fi
}

function _GPA {
    local cur
    cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
    COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -S/ -d ~/Documents/Apps/PythonApps/$cur | cut -b 18- ) )
}


complete -o nospace -F _GPA goToPythonApp
```

[Complete Info on how to do this](https://sixohthree.com/867/bash-completion)

Comment: Thanks. Used the technique suggested in your answer then I got a `command not found for complete`.

Then I added `autoload bashcompinit && bashcompinit` before I source the `.bash_rc file`

The `command not found for complete` was gone but the tab still doesn't work

Comment: you said you use bash bro ?

Comment: can you kindly change your default shell to bash

Comment: or, put the script in a different file then do `. script.sh` , then do `goToPythonApp [TAB]` @KimStacks

Comment: Thanks for the help you give :) When the bounty opens tomorrow, I will give you some token points as thanks. The other answer works way better for my situation.